# php-fpm dockerfile kafka does not load

Tags: php, docker, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I have a dockerfile as below.

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        sed \
        zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        zip \
        unzip \
        nano \
        openssl \
        libssl-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap \
    && apt-get install -y zip libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && apt-get install -y supervisor

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

RUN ( \
                cd /tmp \
                && mkdir librdkafka \
                && cd librdkafka \
                && git clone https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka.git . \
                && ./configure \
                && make \
                && make install \
            )
RUN apt-get install -y librdkafka-dev && pecl install rdkafka
RUN echo "extension=rdkafka.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/rdkafka.ini
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql
RUN pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/mongodb.ini
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN cd ~
RUN sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN echo 'cd /var/www/html/app' >> ~/.bashrc
```

I think it installed the Kafka extension.Because rdkafka appears in the phpinfo output.
However, Rdkafka is not installed as a PHP extension. Therefore, I cannot use kafka.

What could be the reason for this. What am I doing wrong for Docker.

Comment: 1) You don't need to compile anything if `librdkafka-dev` gives you want to want. 2) Are you sure `extension=rdkafka.so` or `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/rdkafka.ini` are correct?

Comment: You installed kafka in a correct way, I guess something else is not correct. please check `php -i | grep kafka`

Answer (score 1):

- Use [docker-php-extension-installer](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer) for easy installation.

OR

- Compile `librdkafka` **or** install `librdkafka-dev`. Next, install `rdkafka` extension `docker-php-ext-install rdkafka` [[detail]](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-install) and enable `docker-php-ext-enable rdkafka` [[detail]](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/master/docker-php-ext-enable).